# min-width doesn't scale down image correctly?

Tags: html, css

My css for a background image doesn't "scale down" the image so you can actually view it, i've used min and max width, to no effect. I'm trying to do this task via html/css only, thanks! If a solution could be made without using absolute positioning that'd be great, because I do want this to be responsive.

The placeholder image I want scaled down: http://socialnewsdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/iStock-Unfinished-Business-11.jpg

My code below:
https://jsfiddle.net/L5e2myxj/6/

html:

```
<h1>Our Thinking</h1>
<p style="color: red;">ocibus apeirian sententiae ex pri, id est altera delectus deterruisset. Admodum civibus nam et, ullum expetenda adipiscing nec eu. Eam an dicam dicant consectetuer. Alii zril gubergren te mei. Sit et natum simul sententiae, case meis dolores eam no. Cum ex verear animal, eruditi ancillae eos e</p>

<div class="article">
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque quo eveniet eaque magni accusantium iste provident ipsum velit odio vel, architecto quia officiis distinctio est, delectus soluta corporis, consectetur nobis?</p>
    <div class="background-img">
      <div class="link"> Read More</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut aspernatur ducimus debitis laudantium repudiandae dignissimos, repellendus tempore reiciendis nostrum, amet animi iure laborum veritatis dolores labore est obcaecati sit ullam.</p>
    <div class="background-img">
      <div class="link"> Read More</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dol minima, quam similique eum ipsam.</p>
    <div class="background-img">
      <div class="link"> Read More</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati quis sed, modi voluptatum provident incidunt voluptatibus aspernatur perferendis dolores illo voluptates ab, voluptate nulla. Minima nihil dicta, est possimus eligendi!Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, reprehenderit, quas! Cupiditate esse perferendis dicta ad, error, quasi, iure dignissimos totam magnam dolores at, eos officia. Dolorum ad dicta accusantium.</p>
    <div class="background-img">
      <div class="link"> Read More</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, voluptas alias cupiditate officiis delectus autem qui, natus aliquid illum molestias illo possimus placeat obcaecati dolor porro recusandae numquam. Nam, recusandae.Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum quam nihil veritatis dolores veniam hic cumque dolor, numquam! Temporibus amet nemo beatae repellat eius exercitationem ad voluptates cupiditate laborum blanditiis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Similique ex nam, amet fugiat architecto praesentium iure dicta, debitis excepturi officiis dolor rem minima sapiente aliquid animi reiciendis et quam pariatur.</p>
    <div class="background-img">
      <div class="link"> Read More</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure accusantium optio cum. Magnam rerum sunt eligendi dolores, recusandae minima, repudiandae hic vero laboriosam mollitia, odit cum. Tempora sed fugiat consequuntur.</p>
    <div class="background-img">
      <div class="link"> Read More</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dol accusantium reprehenderit sint a officiis neque.</p>
    <div class="background-img">
      <div class="link"> Read More</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis repellat aut tempora aspernatur tenetur possimus ipsum assumenda id esse in quos, cum enim dolorum fuga blanditiis. At perferendis, porro iure!</p>
    <div class="background-img">
      <div class="link"> Read More</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat commodi dignissimos aut soluta debitis laborum, unde voluptates aliquam, iste ne esse magni.</p>
          <div class="link"> Read More</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

css:

```
@import "compass/css3";
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.article {
  -moz-column-width: 26em;
  -webkit-column-width: 26em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  width: 100%;
  background: #DBDBDB;
}

p {
  padding: 1;
  margin-top: 1em 0;
}


/*  styles for background color, etc; not necessary for this thing to work  */

.background-img {
  min-height: 5em;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-image: url(http://socialnewsdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/iStock-Unfinished-Business-11.jpg);
}

body {
  font-family: "Garamond", serif;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.25;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
}
```

**edit I found a better solution**

```
   -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
```

This should both scale down the image and scale it up, but be wary it will skew proportions, which you can fix as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Do you need the height on the divs with the images to be responsive too or should those remain static?

Comment: The height should be responsive actually, because I want the entire image in the div but stretched.

Comment: you need to be using `background-size` property to size a background image, not `max-width` and `max-height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `background-size` css property, in particular:

```
background-size: cover;
```

The width attribute applies to the `div` element itself, not the background image.

Comment: he might want to use `background-size: contain;` if he wants the whole image to always be view-able and to not crop

Comment: @zgood the only problem is that i just doesn't look as good. Contain will repeat the image or if you disable repeat it's rather tiny.

Comment: Yeah so right now, I'm trying to figure out how to stretch the image width while not repeating it.

Comment: @OrangeMan. you pretty much have to use the option in my answer. Then tweak positioning and height of the div to reveal more of the image. You don't want to squish it, breaking proportions.

Comment: Yes you would probably use `background-repeat: no-repeat;` with it. Ya I would personally use `cover` like you suggested... it's just he said in the post that he wanted people to  "_actually view it_" so I was guessing he didn't want it cropped

Comment: @OrangeMan. also be aware that you are trying to fit a square into a rectangle (they have different aspect ratio's)... so something will have to give. Either it will be cropped or it will be skewed and dis-proportioned. You might have to give a height to your `.background-img` or use the aspect ratio padding-top trick

Comment: Use background-size: cover, and background-position x% y% to show whatever you want from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this with `background-size`

Don't forget for the other browsers:

```
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to allow the height to fit into the box either.

Comment: @OrangeMan. try `contain` instead of `cover`